Is there a way to set breakpoints on key words in the code (while for) in one click on VS 2022 or Eclipse
I have a bug in a big project with a lot of sources. It seems to be in a loop because the executable does not stop. I would like to put breakpoints on all the "while" and "for" because I have absolutely no idea where the problem is located which seems more "random", at least I don't know how to provoke it at will .
I'm searching a method to do that on Visual Studio C++ 2022 or Eclipse. I need to proceed by running the project in debug mode, then use the application and when the bug emerges, put the breakpoints.

This question is similar to: Programmatically apply / deactivate breakpoints in Visual Studio. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Alternative: Run the program in the debugger, wait until it locks up, and then pause the program. If you don't recognize where in the program you are, check the backtrace and follow it back until you do recognize. It's not just loops you have to watch out for, you may have a deadlock or the program may have called a blocking operation that is never satisfied. You might even have found a dreaded goto footgun.

I agree with @user4581301. Just run your code in the Visual Studio 2022 IDE and press pause on the debugging toobar. Then switch the "Stack Frame" on the debug toolbar to your code to see exactly what part of your code is running at the time and inspect the variables in your code.

You could put the keyword while or for on a separate line and see if Visual Studio allows you to put a breakpoint on the line.  The alternative is to display the assembly language and place a breakpoint on the assembly language instruction that you believe represents the while or for keyword.

Another suggestion is to use "print statement debugging".  Place print statements throughout the code, especially bracketing your questionable loops.  One advantage is that you get a log of how your program is actually behaving. :-)  Rather than printing to the console, you could append to a log file.

@ThomasMatthews print statement debugging can help... but it also can introduce timing differences which if it is a multithreaded application can change the behavior of race conditions making the bug not reproducable. In general I just trust my source code as (possibly unit tests) and a debugger

Attach a debugger and pause it while it is "hanging" then investigate the callstack or callstacks if there are multiple threads, instead of a loop you can also have ended in a deadlock (which can happen in really big projects)

What kind of C++ project are you using? Is it multithreaded?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
